# Find extremal of the functional

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$J(u)=u(0)+0.5 u(0)^2 + \int[u'(t)]^2 dt$$

$u(0)$ unsepecified

$u(1)=2$

I know it solved by e-lagrang equation But i dont know which one

How i can concered with $u(0)$ which is out of integral

And what about bc $u(0)$ unspecified

Comment: Any help please????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
 δJ(u)&=δu(0)+ u(0)·δu(0) + 2·\int_0^1 u'(t)·δu'(t) dt
  \\
  &=(1+u(0))·δu(0)+2·[u'(t)·δu(t)]_0^1-2·\int_0^1 u''(t)·δu(t)
\end{align}
with $δu(1)=0$. Which implies $u''=0$ with $u(0)-2·u'(0)=-1$.

Comment: What`s the name of the method which you use it ?   I want learn it thank you very much

Comment: This is just taking the variational or functional derivative, partial integration and setting the coefficients of $δu$, i.e., the functional derivative, to zero. Exactly the same process that gives the Euler-Lagrange equations. But sometimes it is more educational to do the details by hand and not by recipe.

Comment: If ther is .......tu(t)  how i can derivative it? Thank you this was very helpful

Comment: In general, $δJ(u)=\frac d{ds}J(u+s·δu)|_{s=0}$, so that $δ(t·u(t))=t·δu(t)$. The variation is all in direction of $u$, not at all in the direction of $t$.