# Boundary value problem $u''(t) = 0$, $u(1) = 2$, $2u'(0) = u(0) + \frac{1}{2}[u(0)]^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I find the solution $u(t)$ when
$$u''(t)=0$$

$$u(1)=2$$

$$2u'(0)=u(0)+ \frac 1 2 [u(0)]^2$$

Comment: What does $u''(t) = 0$ tell you about the type of function you are dealing with?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190630/find-extremal-of-the-functional

Comment: I was solving this integral by e-lagrang equation

Comment: The last equation i have got it by natural boundry

Comment: Think carefully, what does $u''(t) = 0$ tell you? Nothing to do with EL equation just one variable calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it just by integrating $u$.

That means $u'(t)=C$ for some real constant $C$.

And $u(t)=Cx+K$ for some other real constant $K$.

Now you have to impose the given conditions in order to determine what $K$ and $C$ are.

From $u(1)=2$ you get $K+C=2$

And $2u'(0)=u(0)+u(0)^2/2$ becomes $2C=K+K^2/2$.

Comment: How i can get valus of c and k?

Comment: solving that two equations